# Asynchronous action methods with synchronous API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, multitasking

I have an action method that inserts some data into the database. I'm trying to make it asynchronous. The code looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyClass model)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                repository.Insert(model);

                anotherSyncCall(model);
            }
            catch { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error"); }
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    });
}
```

Repository's insert method is synchronous, do I have to make it asynchronous to make this action method asynchronous?

Repository Insert code:

```
private EFDbContext context;
public Repository()
{
    context = new EFDbContext(Authentication.GetConnectionClaim);
}
//......
public void Insert(T entity)
{
    context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This a picture of  timings, under repetitive requests.

[image]

As you can see they're working synchronously. I'm sure that my client side Ajax calls are async, because all of the requests are made at once and they receive their responses over time.

*UPDATE*

This is the code that I'm testing my app with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://192.168.1.8/xx/xx/Read',
            data: 'sort=&page=1&pageSize=10&group=&filter='
        });
    }
```

And I've tried setting `SessionState` to `Readonly` as @Dan suggested but id didn't change the timings.

[image]

On the second thought, maybe it's `ToDataSourceResult` extension method of Kendo UI that is causing this issue? But I'm making a different `Task` for this `action method` anyway.

Comment: Might be worthwhile posting the client side code as well.

Comment: For this test, it's a simple JQuery Ajax call in a loop! But for the functionality I'm using Kendo Grid (you don't write custom Ajax calls for that).

Comment: What exactly is `repo`? As the code looks this all should be asynchronous as it is. But I guess that `repo.Insert` does some synchronisation that leads to the observed timing.

Comment: `Rep`, is an EF repository and as I've mentioned it is synchronous. So to make this action method asynchronous I have to make the insert method of the repository asynchronous too? What about other synchronous calls that I have in this action method?

Comment: The problem is not that `Insert` is a synchronous method, but that it probably _synchronises_ the tasks as it uses resources (eg database tables/rows) that can only be used by one thread at a time. So the other tasks are blocked until the currently inserting task is done.

Comment: Rene, I edited my question to share `Insert` code.

Comment: @Akbari you should use unitofwork pattern for db insert, instead of having savechanges inside insert you should have it on unitofwork

Comment: @Akbari the code looks Async. Check your Jquery calls. However, if you want end to end async, you will have to make your repository methods Async aswell. EF offers async methods - `public async Task<TObject> AddAsync(TObject t)
        {
            _context.Set<TObject>().Add(t);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return t;
        }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Preet, if you look at the timings, all of the requests are started exactly at the same time. So I think JQuery code is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting your SessionState to ReadOnly? This can be done on the controller with:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

According to Microsoft:

> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished. (The second session can also get access if the exclusive lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data. However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using Task.Run in a synchronous method by nature, does not mean your code will perform faster. You will rather ended up blocking your server responsiveness (as shown in your pictures). Server cannot process all these requests at the same time, that is why you get above behavior.  If your intention is a non-blocking behavior in the client side. You should call this synchronous method using ajax from the client side so user would not freeze. If you want to dive into async/await in the server side mostly is used for apps that have a limited amount of users, I recommend you this slides [Stephen Cleary Conference](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/slides-available-thatconference-2013.html) as well as reading his blog.